# How to solve following multiple interface classes in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class Test which implements to different interface Interface1 and Interface2. There is a FactoryClass that creates an object of this class Test.

```
class Interface1{   
    virtual void function1() = 0;
};

class Interface2{
       virtual void function2() = 0;
};

class Test(): public Interface1, public Interface2{
void function1()
{
}
void function2()
{
}
};
class FactoryClass
{
    Interface1* createInstance() {
    Interface1* interface1 = new Test();
    return  interface1;        
}
};

void main()
{
    Interface1* int1 = FactoryClass::createInstance();
    int1->function1();

}
```

I need a solution to access function2 via interface2 wihtout doing new again?

Comment: have you tried casting int1 to Interface2?

Comment: The object returned by createInstance() *happens* to implement Interface2.  But I'd say "cast it to Interface2*" is a shaky solution because doing that goes against everything that interfaces are actually for.  In this case I can't see why you couldn't new up a second one, or at least have the factory handle the casting.

Comment: @SteveHoward, I'd argue that that is not necessarily a technical issue. If he's looking for an elegant pattern than yeah, I agree with you that he shouldn't just cast without somehow making sure the cast can succeed but that is a design problem and one that can be solved in different ways, one of which being a QueryInterface approach similar to COM.

Comment: FactoryClass normally are designed to create 1 type of objects that inherited from an interface. If your FactoryClass are designed to return two different type of interface, and class Test happen to implemented both interfaces, you could do it like this
CreateInterface1Instance -> return (Interface1*)CreateTest();
CreateInterface2Instance-> return (Interface2*)CreateTest();
And you can return TestClass in your CreateTest function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have lots of errors, like declaring functions `function1` and `function2` as private.

After fixing the errors, your code compiles fine.

```
class Interface1
{   
    public:
        virtual void function1() = 0;
};

class Interface2
{   
    public:
        virtual void function2() = 0;
};

class Test : public Interface1, public Interface2
{
public:
    void function1()
    {   

    }
    void function2()
    {

    }
};

class FactoryClass
{
public:
    static auto createInstance() {
        return new Test();        
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto int1 = FactoryClass::createInstance();
    int1->function1();
    int1->function2();
}
```

#### [LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/3bJhTC)